# How do you skip a unit test in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, skip, django-unittest

How do forcibly skip a unit test in Django?

@skipif and @skipunless is all I found, but I just want to skip a test right now for debugging purposes while I get a few things straightened out.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Python's unittest module has a few decorators:

There is plain old `@skip`:

```
from unittest import skip

@skip("Don't want to test")
def test_something():
    ...
```

If you can't use `@skip` for some reason, `@skipIf` should work.  Just trick it to always skip with the argument `True`:

```
@skipIf(True, "I don't want to run this test yet")
def test_something():
    ...
```

[unittest docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html)

[Docs on skipping tests](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures)

If you are looking to simply not run certain test files, the best way is probably to use `fab` or other tool and run particular tests.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that you could trick the interpreter with that True argument.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on possible reasons for not being able to use `@skip`?

Comment: You can even skip TestCase classes.

Comment: That's great! 
I did it that way: Put a "SKIP_STRESS_TESTS = True" variable in settings.py and then a "@skipIf(SKIP_STRESS_TESTS, "Will not test this class this time")" on top of the heavy load classes, for me to test once in a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 90):

Django 1.10 [allows use of tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#tagging-tests) for unit tests. You can then use the `--exclude-tag=tag_name` flag to exclude certain tags:

```
from django.test import tag

class SampleTestCase(TestCase):

    @tag('fast')
    def test_fast(self):
        ...

    @tag('slow')
    def test_slow(self):
        ...

    @tag('slow', 'core')
    def test_slow_but_core(self):
        ...
```

In the above example, to exclude your tests with the "`slow`" tag you would run:

```
$ ./manage.py test --exclude-tag=slow
```

Comment: Is there an opposite to `--exclude-tag`, e.g. `--include-tag` but this command is non-existent.

Comment: @JohnnyQ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#tagging-tests